# How can i get the special price of the product if it is active using product id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, special-price

How can i get the special price of the product if it is active ?

Answer (score 1):

```
You will need to load product by product id and then get special price
```

**With Object Manager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

echo "<pre/>";
print_r($productData);

I will suggest you use Factory method to get product detail as per Magento Standard.
```

Comment: i am getting the special .But if it is not active also i am getting the special.i mean if the To date is over also iam getting the special price.